# SLF4J LogBack - multiple loggers and appanders

Tags: logback, slf4j

I need guidance for a logging requirement I am having.
My application got two services - upload and download.
I need to maintain separate logs for both - So far I have done below in logback.xml

```
<appender name="DownloadAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>download.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>download.log_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>

    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator> <!-- defaults to type ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator -->
            <expression>logger.equals("DownloadLogger")</expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
    </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="UploadAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>upload.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>upload.log_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%i.zip</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>

    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator> <!-- defaults to type ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator -->
            <expression>logger.equals(UploadLogger")</expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
    </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="DownloadLogger" level="DEBUG" additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="DownloadAppender" />
</logger>

<logger name="UploadLogger" level="DEBUG" additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="UploadAppender" />
</logger>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

Usage of defined loggers in application is used by respective service classes.
ie classes of upload service obtain logger by

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger("UploadLogger")
```

and vice-versa for DownloadLogger.

Upon running the service I notice that only upload.log is created and filled in.
download.log gets created but no content are logged in it .

I suspect usage of filter is incorrect but I couldn't find any solution yet such that both log files can be maintained properly.

Can someone please help me how to correct the config?

Answer (score 0):

The above config is fit for the purpose. The problem was in the way logback.xml was provided as command line argument.

The problem was resolved after providing logback.xml with -Dlogback.configurationFile